# Remove just the last "." in line

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I don't now how to remove just the last "." in the end of line and don't impact the others "." in middle of line, this is an example :

```
"1","php.ect.D221211.T222012.M845539.MIMEOUT","O","I","E","ect","5834","php","mp-mp","redd","221211 222030","0".
```

Thanks

Comment: What would the expected result be?

Comment: . is regex so `-split '\.'`

Comment: If you mean _trim_ (remove) rather than _split_: `'"1.2","3".'.TrimEnd('.')`

Comment: Please show in code what you have tried and what the result should look like.

Comment: it work very well with TrimEnd, thanks so much

Comment: Glad to hear it, @oussama_tr. I've posted the solution as an answer, which allows it to be [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777). I also encourage you to revisit your previous questions and accept answers there, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To remove (trim, strip) one or more instances of a given character (or multiple ones) only from the *end* of a string, use its [`.TrimEnd()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.TrimEnd) method.

A simplified example:

```bash
'"1.2","3".'.TrimEnd('.') # -> '"1.2","3"', i.e. the trailing "." is gone.
```